# AngularJS Nested accordian using ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I want to create an accordion in AngularJS using UI Bootstrap with a Parent-Child relationship.

Issue 1:  A Parent can have n number of Siblings and Childs also.

Issue 2:  A Child can have n number of inner Child also. so it has to be deep nested till the last Child.

Issue 3: A Parent can have no Childs also.

```
[
   {
        "bu_id": 8,
        "tenant_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "bu_name": "Parent 2",
        "created_date": "2016-06-26 11:31:07",
        "updated_date": "2016-06-26 11:31:07",
        "parent_id": null
    },{
        "bu_id": 9,
        "tenant_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "bu_name": "Child Of Parent 2",
        "created_date": "2016-06-26 11:31:47",
        "updated_date": "2016-06-26 11:31:47",
        "parent_id": 8
    },{
        "bu_id": 10,
        "tenant_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "bu_name": "inner Child Parent 2",
        "created_date": "2016-06-26 11:36:30",
        "updated_date": "2016-06-26 11:36:30",
        "parent_id": 9
    },{
        "bu_id": 11,
        "tenant_id": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "bu_name": "Parent 3",
        "created_date": "2016-06-26 11:36:30",
        "updated_date": "2016-06-26 11:36:30",
        "parent_id": null
    }
]
```

[Tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0I94.png)

the child and parent are identified on bu_id and parent_id.

Comment: did you 'check http://ezraroi.github.io/ngJsTree/ ?

Comment: @singhakash i dont wont to use a plugin i want to do it with custom code

Answer (score 0):

I use the [ng-repeat-end](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive to handle this scenario.  Markup would look something like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.label}}</li>
  <li ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.children">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.children">{{item.label}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can create a directive with a template for the 'child' items so that it will go as deep as your hierarchy:

```
angular.module.directive('itemRepeater', function() {
    return {
        template: '<ul>' +
                  '  <li ng-repeat="item in item.children">' +
                  '    {{item.label}}' +
                  '    <li ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.children">' +
                  '      <item-repeater></item-repeater>' +
                  '    </li>' +
                  '  </li>' +
                  '</ul>';
    }
})
```

Then:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.label}}</li>
  <li ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.children">
    <item-repeater></item-repeater>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can u pls provide a plunker